# LINQ outer join gives error

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

The following LINQ statement (a simple outer join) in C# throws a wild exception:

```
var query = 
        from cs in db.scan
        join cp in db.patient on cc.pid equals cp.pid into cpGroup
        from cp2 in cpGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new 
        { 
            Name = ((cp2 == null) ? 
                String.Empty : 
                cp2.plastname + ", " + cp2.pfirstname), 
            DOB = ((cp2 == null) ? 
                DateTime.MinValue : 
                cp2.pdateofbirth) 
        };
```

Exception:

> Auf die Variable "cp2" vom Typ "Core.patient" wird vom Bereich "" verwiesen, sie ist jedoch nicht definiert.

Translated:

> The variable "cp2" of type "Core.patient" is refered to by area "" but it is not defined.

What is wrong here? Btw. this error can not be catched by a surrounding try catch block...

Comment: Try making the select just `select new { Test = cp2 }`.  Does it still error?

Comment: Yep, still an error...

Comment: I don't have any idea.  Try putting it into [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net) and using the `.Dump()` function to see what it looks like?

Comment: 'cc.pid equals', you mean cs.pid equals, right?

Comment: also, is patient a normal list of a normal class, or is it a enitty from entity framework, and you are try to use this query to load data from database?

Answer (score -1):

There are probably issues with the join.  This is the linqish way to accomplish the same thing.

```
 var query = 
    from cs in db.scan
    from cp in db.patient
    where cs.pid == cp.pid
    select new 
    { 
        Name = cp.plastname + ", " + cp.pfirstname), 
        DOB = cs.pdateofbirth
    };
```

Comment: This is how I would also do it

Comment: 1) This is an inner join, not an outer join, as the OP is trying to get. 2) This is doing a Cartesian product and then filtering that down, which is *dramatically* less efficient than a Join, as a join can be optimized much more heavily.